# Xcode 10.2 is not showing autocompletion

Tags: xcode, macos, autocomplete, macos-mojave, xcode10.2

Recently I have downloaded `Xcode 10.2` from the `App Store`. I started using it. And I observe that my `Xcode` is not showing autosuggestion or autocompletion when I am writing code.

Anyone have any idea about it ? Is I missed anything ? Should it required any extra settings like enable/disable or anything ?

I tried severaI havel differnent things:

- Clear derived data
- Restart Mac
- Restart XCode
- Rebuild

I'm using macOS 10.14.4

[image]